# When can I use $timeout(angular.noop)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Recently I purchased a code and after analyzing I found a strange code.
Here `$timeout(angular.noop)` was used something like refresh.
I mean if I delete $timeout(angular.noop) ng-repeat list is not refreshed.
I also tried to change `$timeout(angular.noop)` to `angular.noop` but not working.
Is there anyone who knows exact functionality of `$timeout(angular.noop)`?

Comment: i'm guessing its a lazy way to force a root scope digest.

Comment: i would readup on the digest cycle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, that line evaluates changes between models and views and update UI and Model to be in sync.

As it's explained in more detail [here](https://www.codingeek.com/angularjs/angular-js-apply-timeout-digest-evalasync/)

`$timeout` calls `rootScope.$apply()` which calls `rootScope.$digest()` but without the risk of getting `digest is already in progress` error.

Comment: what is 'digest is already in progress' error?
Can you make more detailed answer?

Comment: That error occurs when you try to update the View and a previous updating is being processed.